# How to run react and django development servers in single Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My current Dockerfile as follows

```
# base image
FROM node:14
# react
WORKDIR 'frontend'
COPY frontend/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY frontend .
CMD ["npm", "start"]

# django
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR 'server'
COPY server/requirements.txt ./server/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY server ./server
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

If I comment out react or django, other will work. Unfortunately I can't make it work together. Is there a way to run them together in single Dockerfile?

Comment: I might suggest `RUN npm build` or something similar in the first stage to compile the front-end application to static files, then something like `COPY --from=frontend /frontend/dist ./static` in the second stage to serve it as static files.

Answer (score 0):

user9066046 - You trying to run 2 docker containers in one file - there is **docker-compose** for running multicontainers -
simultaneously:

Also here it's possibility to pass ENV_VARIABLES for specific environment (DEV, QA ,UAT, PROD) etc.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  react:
    build: .
    image: react
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  django:
    image: django
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
```

For it the name image - from which the containers are to be constructed.